# Material ui breakpoints not working correctly in NextJs SSR

Tags: next.js, material-ui, responsive-design, server-side-rendering, sx

I am using Material ui sx styling with breakpoints, for example:

```
<Box
    sx={{
      height: 233,
      width: 350,
      maxHeight: { xs: 233, md: 167 },
      maxWidth: { xs: 350, md: 250 },
    }}
  />
```

Because I am using Nextjs and SSR (ISR),

it cause an issue that when the page rendered it rendered twice one time with incorrect breakpoint values
and then the user experience big CLS - Cumulative Layout Shift

How can I work with Material ui sx styling breakpoints and prevent this first render with incorrect values?